# species accumulation curve for one site in R using specaccum

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I have one site which has 69 species with different abundances. I want to plot the species accumulation curve for that one site. But the function specaccum (vegan package) in R asks for multiple sites. and on searching further I saw the method of rarefaction which gives me the same result as earlier. And doesn't seem to give any results for only one site. Could someone please guide me about it ?

Answer (score 4):

`specaccum` indeed accumulates sites -- and there is not much to accumulate in one site. However, like your wrote, rarefaction is for one site, and **vegan** function `rarecurve` will plot rarefaction curve for one site (provided the abundances can be interpreted as counts).

Comment: Thanks Jari Oksanen and Gavin Simpson  :-)